# Word for an experience or entity that is enjoyable with repeated exposure, but not interesting or unpleasant if experienced once or a few times?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've seen

> Age like wine

to describe this phenomenon, but I'm thinking that there's a single word or a more concise and descriptive phrase for this. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It would normally be described as an "acquired taste".

Comment: +1 -- my gut reaction. Something that you need to put a little effort into to come to appreciate, e.g. wine, (modern) art :-), Jazz, cheese, contemporary music, James Joyce, and so much more. (list is not complete)

Comment: Semantically speaking, it's the definitive answer, and certainly what most people would choose, but it's not a single word.

Comment: OP asked for a " single word or a more concise and descriptive phrase".