# What is a similar word or phrase to 'Marmite' to describe something that you start off hating, but grow to love – or vice versa?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

We're fairly all aware of 'Marmite' – *love it or hate it*. As in "X's music is Marmite". Or 'a Marmite thing'.

But what would be a similar way to describe something that you start off hating, but grow to love – or vice versa?

Comment: [Word for an experience or entity that is enjoyable with repeated exposure, but not interesting or unpleasant if experienced once or a few times?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28239/word-for-an-experience-or-entity-that-is-enjoyable-with-repeated-exposure-but-n/) Doesn't seem the same question but the answer is probably similar.

Comment: Marmite is not well known in the US, btw.

Comment: There is 'acquired taste' at the part-duplicate @Stuart mentions, which is a perfect fit. // We refer to something that no longer has its initial appeal as having 'lost its charm', being 'past its sell-by date', 'passé' etc. Probably this second question is a duplicate of [word for something that used to be popular but not anymore](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/510714/word-for-something-that-used-to-be-popular-but-not-anymore/510716#510716).

Comment: @TimR - probably a UK thing. I'd be interested as to the US equivalent (and phrase).

Comment: Also known as [vegemite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegemite). Marmite is a UK brand name.

Comment: Would you be all right with one word meaning "something you initially dislike, but come to like with repeated exposure" and a different word meaning "something you initially like, but come to dislike with repeated exposure," or are you specifically looking for a single word that includes both cases?

Comment: @TannerSwett - two words/phrases for essentially the opposites would be fine - or even one for one of them is appreciated.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't think vegemite is well known here, either. I associate it with Australia.

Comment: The first paragraph describes a "love it or hate it" relationship, but the title and second paragraph describe a change in affection over time. Those are different concepts. Perhaps your intention would be clearer if you [included a sample sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: I don't know of anything similar to Marmite in the US.

Comment: @StuartF, the operative part of this question (as it is now, after several edits) is effectively the same as that earlier question; the love-or-hate part seems to be just a confusing distraction.

Answer (score 1):

> X's music is a grower.

> X's music grows on you.

From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/grower)

> Grower
>
> 3. a piece of music that is initially unimpressive but becomes more enjoyable after further hearings

Comment: "a grower" is a slang neologism. Not rejecting it, however, just pointing that out that many people wouldn't know what that meant. There is the long-standing form, "his music grows on you" as you say, which is more widely used and known.